# SDL2: getting segmentation fault with TTF_RenderText after some time?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, sdl, sdl-2

Well, I wasn't sure if that's for code review or for this site, but it has a problem, so I suppose I'm in the right place. I'm trying to create a game using C and SDL. Here's the code(explanation below):

```
//Includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <SDL2_gfxPrimitives.h>


//Create some global variables(is there some other way to do that?)
SDL_Window *screen;
SDL_Renderer *renderer;
SDL_Texture *tardis;
SDL_Surface *tardis_surface;
SDL_Texture *gallifrey;
SDL_Surface *gallifrey_surface;
SDL_Surface *pillar_surface;
SDL_Rect tardis_dest;


//Some variables I want to keep throughout the game
float speed = 0;
int pillars = 0;
int pause = 0;


//Those two could change in the future
int WIDTH = 640;
int HEIGHT = 480;


//Define a struct to express the pillars in a better way
typedef struct{
    SDL_Rect pillar_up;
    SDL_Rect pillar_down;
    SDL_Texture *pillar_texture;
}pillar;


//OK, that might be silly, but I create a list of pointers so
//that I can keep track of them afterwards. Is that bad?
pillar *list_dest[4];


//Generate a pillar
void create_pillar(int pillars_no, int xpos)
{
    //Generate random height
    int height = rand() % 200;
    if(height < 50)
        height += 50;
    pillar pillar_dest;

    //Set the coordinates for the upper pillar
    pillar_dest.pillar_up.x = xpos;
    pillar_dest.pillar_up.y = 0;
    pillar_dest.pillar_up.w = 70;
    pillar_dest.pillar_up.h = HEIGHT - (height + 180);

    //Set the coordinates for the pillar on the ground
    pillar_dest.pillar_down.x = xpos;
    pillar_dest.pillar_down.y = HEIGHT - height;
    pillar_dest.pillar_down.w = 70;
    pillar_dest.pillar_down.h = 200;

    //Set the pillar texture
    pillar_dest.pillar_texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(
                                renderer, pillar_surface);

    //Allocate space for the pillar and save the address
    //in the list_dest
    pillar *pillar_destp = malloc(sizeof(pillar_dest));
    *pillar_destp = pillar_dest;
    list_dest[pillars_no % 3] = pillar_destp;
}


//Check if the Tardis collides with a pillar
int check_collision(SDL_Rect A, SDL_Rect B)
{
    //The sides of the rectangles
    int leftA, leftB;
    int rightA, rightB;
    int topA, topB;
    int bottomA, bottomB;

    //Calculate the sides of rect A
    leftA = A.x;
    rightA = A.x + A.w;
    topA = A.y;
    bottomA = A.y + A.h;

    //Calculate the sides of rect B
    leftB = B.x;
    rightB = B.x + B.w;
    topB = B.y;
    bottomB = B.y + B.h;

    //If any of the sides from A are outside of B
    if(bottomA < topB)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if(topA > bottomB)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(rightA < leftB)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(leftA > rightB)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    //Else
    return 1;
}


//Render the pillars(shitty function name, whatever...)
void draw_ground()
{
    //I always create 3 pillars, no more
    if(pillars < 3)
    {
        create_pillar(pillars, WIDTH + pillars * 240);
        pillars += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            //Free the previous pillars
            pillar *current_pillar;
            current_pillar = list_dest[i];
            if(current_pillar->pillar_up.x < -70)
            {
                free(current_pillar->pillar_texture);
                free(current_pillar);
                create_pillar(pillars, WIDTH);
                pillars += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                //Check if the Tardis has collided with a pillar and
                //display a "game over" message.
                if(check_collision(current_pillar->pillar_up, tardis_dest) ||
                    check_collision(current_pillar->pillar_down, tardis_dest))
                {
                    SDL_Rect target;
                    target.x = (WIDTH / 2) - 100;
                    target.y = (HEIGHT / 2) - 50;
                    target.w = 200;
                    target.h = 100;
                    TTF_Font *font;
                    font = TTF_OpenFont("DALEK.ttf", 40);
                    SDL_Surface *text;
                    SDL_Color text_color = {255, 255, 0};
                    text = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,
                    "GAME OVER",
                    text_color);
                    SDL_Texture *game_over;
                    game_over = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, text);
                    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, game_over, NULL, &target);
                    pause = 1;
                    int j;
                    for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                    {
                        free(list_dest[j]);
                    }
                    pillars = 0;
                    break;

                }
                //Render the pillars
                double angle = 180.0;
                current_pillar->pillar_up.x -= 10;
                current_pillar->pillar_down.x -= 10;
                SDL_RenderCopyEx(renderer, current_pillar->pillar_texture,
                    NULL, &current_pillar->pillar_up, angle = 0.0,
                    NULL, SDL_FLIP_VERTICAL);
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, current_pillar->pillar_texture,
                    NULL, &current_pillar->pillar_down);
            }
        }
    }
}


//Render the pillar counter
void draw_counter()
{
    SDL_Rect counter;
    counter.x = WIDTH - 50;
    counter.y = 10;
    counter.w = 40;
    counter.h = 50;

    TTF_Font *font;
    font = TTF_OpenFont("DALEK.ttf", 40);

    SDL_Surface *count;
    SDL_Color text_color = {0, 255, 255};

    char count_text[3];
    if(pillars >= 3)
        sprintf(count_text, "%d", pillars - 3);
    else
        sprintf(count_text, "%d", pillars);

    count = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,
    count_text,
    text_color);

    SDL_Texture *pillar_counter;
    pillar_counter = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, count);

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, pillar_counter, NULL, &counter);
    //This is the last function of the game loop, so I suppose it's a good
    //place for the SDL_RenderPresent
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}


//Load the images used in the game
void load_images()
{
    tardis_surface = IMG_Load("files/tardis.bmp");
    gallifrey_surface = IMG_Load("files/gallifrey.bmp");
    pillar_surface = IMG_Load("files/pipe.bmp");
}


//Create the background and the Tardis in it's initial place
void create_sprites()
{
    //Create area for the TARDIS
    tardis_dest.x=50;
    tardis_dest.y=100;
    tardis_dest.w=50;
    tardis_dest.h=80;

    //Color key the TARDIS and create texture
    Uint32 colorkey = SDL_MapRGB(tardis_surface->format,0,0,0);
    //SDL_DisplayFormat(tardis_surface);
    SDL_SetColorKey(tardis_surface, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY, colorkey); // That doesn't work!!!!!
    //Why? Any ideas?

    tardis = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, tardis_surface);

    //Create texture for the Gallifreyan background
    gallifrey = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, gallifrey_surface);

    //Clear the renderer
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    //Add textures to renderer
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, gallifrey, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, tardis, NULL, &tardis_dest);

    //Update renderer
    //SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}


//Update the Tardis' position
void update_sprites(float time)
{
    speed += time * 28;
    if(tardis_dest.y > 460)
    {
        tardis_dest.y = 460;
        speed = 0;
    }
    else if(tardis_dest.y < 0)
    {
        tardis_dest.y = 0;
        speed = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        tardis_dest.y += speed;
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, gallifrey, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, tardis, NULL, &tardis_dest);
        //SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
}


//Change the speed when clicked
void ignite()
{
    if(speed > 0)
        speed = -10;
    else
        speed -= 10;
}


//The main function
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    SDL_Event ev;
    int active = 1;

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize SDL. SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    else
        printf("SDL initialized.\n");

    if(TTF_Init() == 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "TTF initialized.\n");
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize TTF.\n");

    //Open main window
    screen = SDL_CreateWindow
    (
        "First Game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        WIDTH,
        HEIGHT,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
    );

    if(!screen)
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not set video mode: SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(screen, 0, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    //Draw the environment
    load_images();
    create_sprites();

    //Set time
    Uint32 current_time, old_time;
    float time_passed;
    current_time = SDL_GetTicks();

    while(active)
    {
        //Update time
        old_time = current_time;
        current_time = SDL_GetTicks();
        time_passed = (current_time - old_time) / 1000.0f;

        //Handle Events
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&ev))
        {

            if(ev.type == SDL_QUIT)
                active = 0;
            if(ev.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
            {
                if(pause)
                {
                    pause = 0;
                }
                else
                    ignite();
            }
        }
        if(pause)
            continue;
        update_sprites(time_passed);
        draw_ground();
        draw_counter();
        SDL_Delay(40);
    }

    //Exit
    SDL_FreeSurface(tardis_surface);
    SDL_FreeSurface(gallifrey_surface);
    SDL_Quit();
    printf("SDL terminated. Have a nice day...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Quite a read, huh? It probably has many flaws, as it's my first try in game programming, but my main problem is that after some time of playing it I get a segmentation fault. With gdb, I found that it's the following command that's causing the problem:

```
count = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,
    count_text,
    text_color);
```

Located in the draw_counter() function, at line 214(somewhere in the middle). The question is: why? I suppose it has to do with the memory allocation that I'm doing (I'm still learning C and that's a very tricky part, coming from Python). If anyone could give some useful info? Thanks
And BTW, please don't respond with the usual "don't use C, learn C++ or Java" or even "just use Unity", I want to learn C, and maybe learn some game programming along the way.

Comment: Have you tried checking some memory leaks in your game with valgrind?

Comment: Yeah, although I'm still a bit confused with it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be the continuously calling of `font = TTF_OpenFont("DALEK.ttf", 40);` that makes it fail after a time.

SDL allocates memory for every opened font and at some time you are going to run out. (Perhaps the file stays open and your system runs out of file handles.) You need to *close* the font handle: add

```
TTF_CloseFont( font );
```

at the end of the routines that open it. Alternatively, open the fonts only *once* (in your `main`) routine and save their handles in a global variable.

By the way, I also notice you are as liberal with your surfaces. Use a similar function `SDL_FreeSurface` when you're done with one, again to prevent using resources only once but still having them allocated. (That is for SDL 1.0, which I'm used to. Check SDL 2 documentation.)

Comment: Well, that was quick. Thanks a lot! Seems to work just fine now, no segmentation faults.